# Does this sentence sound weird and unnatural? If so, what do you think is a better/correct sentence structure?

Tags: grammar, sentence-patterns, auxiliary-verbs

> It seems this would be the last time we will talk about this.

I don't get the auxiliary verbs (would, will) used in the sentence above. Isn't it better to say, "It seems this would be the last time we talk about this." ?

Comment: It doesn’t sound weird and unnatural.

Answer (score 1):

The tenses are inconsistent. You want one of the following:

- It seems this is the last time we will talk about this.
- It seemed this was the last time we would talk about this.

I think this:

- It seemed this would be the last time we would talk about this.

is unnecessarily wordy.